# In WPF Style, How can I change defined color?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, styles

I am making Image/Text button.
When mouse over event arised, I want to change color of my drawing brush.
How can I this?
In below example, I want to iconBrush's color, Red -> Blue when mouse over.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="iconBrush" Color="Red"/>
<DrawingBrush x:Key="buttonIcon" Stretch="Uniform">
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <DrawingGroup>
            <DrawingGroup.Children>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="{StaticResource iconBrush}" Geometry="... />
            </DrawingGroup.Children>
        </DrawingGroup>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>

<Style x:Key="ImageTextButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    ...
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border>                        
                        <Grid>
                           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                               <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                               <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                           </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="{StaticResource buttonIcon}" />
                            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                                <ContentPresenter ...
                                      />
                        </Grid>

                        </Grid>

                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="{StaticResource iconBrush}" Value="Blue" />
                         ---> I Want to do this way..
```

Comment: what was the issue? post your full xaml code!

Comment: the above code <Setter TargetName="{StaticResource iconBrush}" Value="Blue" /> is non sense.. error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not possible directly the way you are trying to achieve as nested properties or setting the resources values are not supported in setters

here is a workaround

- i moved the drawing brush in background property of grid
- binded brush of geometry drawing brush to background of templated parent which is button
- and then switched the background of the template in the trigger

here is the code

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="iconBrush" Color="Red" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="blueBrush" Color="Blue" />
<Style x:Key="ImageTextButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource iconBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                            <Grid.Background>
                                <DrawingBrush Stretch="Uniform">
                                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                        <DrawingGroup>
                                            <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Geometry="..." />
                                            </DrawingGroup.Children>
                                        </DrawingGroup>
                                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                </DrawingBrush>
                            </Grid.Background>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource blueBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Another approach**

- I defined 2 icons
- set one icon to the background of the grid
- switch to another icon based on the trigger

code

```
<DrawingBrush x.Key="redIcon" Stretch="Uniform">
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <DrawingGroup>
            <DrawingGroup.Children>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="Red" Geometry="..." />
            </DrawingGroup.Children>
        </DrawingGroup>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>

<DrawingBrush x.Key="blueIcon" Stretch="Uniform">
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <DrawingGroup>
            <DrawingGroup.Children>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="Blue" Geometry="..." />
            </DrawingGroup.Children>
        </DrawingGroup>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>

<Style x:Key="ImageTextButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="icon" Background="{StaticResource redIcon}" />
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource blueIcon}" TargetName="icon" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Attached Property for Icon**

class to declare the property and hold the value

```
class Extras: DependencyObject
{
    public static Brush GetIcon(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Brush)obj.GetValue(IconProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIcon(DependencyObject obj, Brush value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IconProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Icon.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Icon", typeof(Brush), typeof(Extras), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

XAML resources

```
<DrawingBrush x:Key="buttonIcon"
                Stretch="Uniform">
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <DrawingGroup>
            <DrawingGroup.Children>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="Red"
                                    Geometry="..." />
            </DrawingGroup.Children>
        </DrawingGroup>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>
<Style x:Key="ImageTextButtonStyle"
        TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="0"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding l:Extras.Icon}" />
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

usage

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ImageTextButtonStyle}"
        Content="Icon Button"
        l:Extras.Icon="{StaticResource buttonIcon}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. but I can not insert drawing brush into style, I will use this style at several buttons that have different image each other. So, I derive Button class, and add icon image property, and use like <local:MyImageTextButton IconImage="{StaticResource someIcon}"...

Comment: deriving is kind of defeating WPF's declarative power, you still have option to use attached properties and attached behaviors for even complex solutions. You can achieve the same without even deriving and it will be a reusable solution if you were supposed to reuse similar logic, eg. Checkbox or radios etc.

Comment: Thanks for your "Another approach", but as I said in above comment, I want to use multi-purpose style. I should inject to a button the icon image. your another approach also binded one style <-> one icon image. this is my problem now, Maybe Is this can be solved with "Attached Properties" you said?

Comment: hi @user3678158 I have added an example for attached property to achieve Icon property in button with the desired style. The example does not have color change on mouse over as of now it demonstrate a simple use of attached properties. You can experiment with the styles and attached properties to achieve the desired result. You can also use an additional property for color which then can be manipulated for mouse over effect.

Comment: Thank you very much, Pushpraj Ruhal, I solved this problem as you advised, To control mouse over icon change, I added one more property in 'Extras' class, So I used as like <Button Style="{StaticResource ImageTextButtonStyle}"
                Content="Icon Button"
                local:Extras.Icon="{StaticResource buttonIcon}"
                local:Extras.Icon2="{StaticResource buttonIcon_mouseOver}"/> So, I can inject icon's image from outer style, and I should use only one style.

Comment: To Pushpraj Ruhal, In your code, Background="{TemplateBinding l:Extras.Icon}" /> is not working, So I replaced that with Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(local:Extras.Icon)}"/> Frankly I don't know the meaning of first code.

Comment: Hi @user3678158 I defined the binding in the control template so I used TemplateBinding for it. TemplateBinding works in the scope of control template. For your case you may need to figure out the correct binding based on the intended location. For instance if I try to use the template binding in drawing brush resource it will not produce any value so in that case I may need to use RelativeSource to figure out the appropriate source just like you have already done. FYI TemplateBinding is just like TemplatedParent with more speed and compile time detection.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved quite simply using [Attached Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You could also override the Button class but I prefer the first solution since you are only templating an existing control. Furthermore, you could reuse the attached property with controls other than Button.

The attached property:

```
public class OnMouseOver : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
      "Background",
      typeof(Brush),
      typeof(OnMouseOver)
    );
    public static void SetBackground(UIElement element, Brush value)
    {
        element.SetValue(BackgroundProperty, value);
    }
    public static Brush GetBackground(UIElement element)
    {
        return (Brush)element.GetValue(BackgroundProperty);
    }
}
```

The XAML part:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="buttonBaseStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                <Setter Property="local:OnMouseOver.Background" Value="Lime" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="8" />
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(local:OnMouseOver.Background)}" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="buttonRedStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource buttonBaseStyle}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="local:OnMouseOver.Background" Value="Pink" />
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="buttonBlueStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource buttonBaseStyle}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                <Setter Property="local:OnMouseOver.Background" Value="Aqua" />
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <UniformGrid Columns="3">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource buttonBaseStyle}" />
        <Button Style="{StaticResource buttonRedStyle}" />
        <Button Style="{StaticResource buttonBlueStyle}" />
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks Raúl Nuño, your answer help me very much. this makes the concept of Attached Property to me. Thanks. :D