# Defining style for GeometryDrawing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-style, geometrydrawing

*Please do not mark it as duplicate. The linked question is simply different from what I'm asking.*

I need to set `Pen` and `Brush` properties for around 180+ `GeometryDrawing` objects. My first thought was to use a `Style` for it, but I learned that `Style` cannot target `GeometryDrawing` because it does not inherit from `FrameworkElement`. I then considered creating my own `GeometryDrawing2` that inherits from `GeometryDrawing` and setting `Pen` and `Brush` in the constructor, but found that `GeometryDrawing` is sealed and can't be inherited.

What is the best way of achieving what I want other than copy-pasting the properties 180 times?

### Edit

Here is my collection of drawings:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <DrawingImage x:Key="Drawing1">
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
      <GeometryDrawing Geometry="..." />
    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
  </DrawingImage>

  <DrawingImage x:Key="Drawing2">
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
      <GeometryDrawing Geometry="..." />
    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
  </DrawingImage>

  <!--180 more such drawings-->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I need to set `Brush` and `Pen` for each of the `GeometryDrawing` objects to say `Red` and `Black`. The usual clean way in XAML is to do this through `Style`, but as I explained above, that doesn't work for `GeometryDrawing`. The only other way is to copy-paste `Brush="{StaticResource MyBrush}"` and `Pen="{StaticResource MyPen}"` to each of the 180+ `GeometryDrawing` objects. Or is there a faster (XAML-only) way?

Comment: Unclear what you mean. Where are you copy/pasting properties? How are you storing the `GeometryDrawing` objects? Why aren't they in a collection that you could enumerate and assign the values that way? Please improve your question so it's clear what you're doing now and what you'd like to be able to do instead, making sure to include a good [mcve] that illustrates all of that.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: See my edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In WPF Style, How can I change defined color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23880582/in-wpf-style-how-can-i-change-defined-color)

Comment: @Funk No duplicate at all. OP has no Style.

Comment: @Clemens Have you read the title?

Comment: @Funk Sure, but apparently you haven't read the body. As OP has realized, you can't define a Style for a GeometryDrawing. The question you've linked asks for something completely different than this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is still incomplete, lacking a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to work with. But, based on the information you've provided so far, I would expect a template-based implementation to solve your problem. For example:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <PathGeometry x:Key="geometry1">...</PathGeometry>
  <PathGeometry x:Key="geometry2">...</PathGeometry>
  <!-- etc. -->

  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type PathGeometry}">
    <DrawingImage>
      <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <GeometryDrawing Geometry="{Binding}" Pen="..." Brush="..."/>
      </DrawingImage.Drawing>
    </DrawingImage>
  </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then when you want to display one of those, just use a `ContentControl` or `ContentPresenter`. For example:

```
<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource geometry1}"/>
```

Comment: Fair enough. That apparently solves the problem at hand. Thanks a lot.